# How to resize dynamically allocated array of std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I created a dynamically allocated array of lists of size 7 which works fine and elements can be pushed to each list in the array. But, when I try to resize the array to size 10 using `realloc`, which seems to give no error, but when I try to push elements to the lists, I get `Segmentation fault` error.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> *slots = new std::list<int>[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        slots[i].push_back(i + 1);
        slots[i].push_back(i + 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        for (const auto &slot : slots[i])
        {
            std::cout << slot << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    slots = (std::list<int> *)realloc(slots, sizeof(std::list<int>) * 10);

    // Segmentation fault
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        slots[i].push_back(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUtput:

```
1 2 
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
Segmentation fault
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to read up on how std::list works. It is (usually) implemented as a non-contiguous storage (a.k.a. linked list), not an array. Besides, 'realloc' and standard containers are never a very good match.

Comment: "Dynamically allocated array" is spelled `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: The most obvious problem is that your code constructs 7 lists and then tries to access 10 lists.

Comment: `std::list<int> *slots = new std::list<int>[7];` -- There is no need to use `new` here -- C++ is not Java, C#, or some other language that requires `new` to create objects.

Comment: `slots = (std::list<int> *)realloc(slots, sizeof(std::list<int>) * 10);` -- Obviously you got this from a book or website dedicated to `C` programming, not C++.  If you used good C++ learning material, you would never had encountered usage of `realloc`, and instead, had learned `std::vector`.  C and C++ are two different languages, and conflating the two of them is what led to the issue you are seeing now.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `realloc` on classes with constructors and destructors (like `std::list`) because `realloc` fails to call the appropriate constructors and destructors. You also cannot use `realloc` on memory allocated with `new`.

Do things the easy way, use a vector (of lists)

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> slots(7);
...
slots.resize(10);
```